# AttributeError: function/symbol 'ARC4_stream_init' not found in library (Python)

Tags: python, pdf, cryptography, pdfminer

I've been trying to use multiple different pdf to text libraries such as pdfplumber and pdfminer, both give me this same traceback error that I am missing ARC4_stream_init. I tried googling but I couldn't find anyone with a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated:

Edit: originally I was trying to extract a financial statement pdf that might be encrypted. I just tried a simpler pdf and there was no issue. I'd still appreciate any workaround as I am trying to automate data entry of financial statement pdfs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Stan\Python\ALIRT\pdf extracter\test.py", line 50, in <module>
    text = convert_pdf_to_txt('test_pdf.pdf')

  File "C:\Users\Stan\Python\ALIRT\pdf extracter\test.py", line 40, in convert_pdf_to_txt
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfpage.py", line 127, in get_pages
    doc = PDFDocument(parser, password=password, caching=caching)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 564, in __init__
    self._initialize_password(password)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 590, in _initialize_password
    handler = factory(docid, param, password)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 283, in __init__
    self.init()

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 291, in init
    self.init_key()

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 304, in init_key
    self.key = self.authenticate(self.password)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 354, in authenticate
    key = self.authenticate_user_password(password)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 361, in authenticate_user_password
    if self.verify_encryption_key(key):

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 368, in verify_encryption_key
    u = self.compute_u(key)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 326, in compute_u
    result = ARC4.new(key).encrypt(hash.digest())  # 4

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py", line 132, in new
    return ARC4Cipher(key, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py", line 60, in __init__
    result = _raw_arc4_lib.ARC4_stream_init(c_uint8_ptr(key),

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 912, in __getattr__
    make_accessor(name)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 908, in make_accessor
    accessors[name](name)

  File "C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 838, in accessor_function
    value = backendlib.load_function(BType, name)

AttributeError: function/symbol 'ARC4_stream_init' not found in library 'C:\Users\Stan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\..\Cipher\_ARC4.cp37-win_amd64.pyd': error 0x7f
```

Comment: PyCryptoDome offers a Python implementation of Arc4 - see doc page: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/arc4.html

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit of a beginner so I am still confused by what I should do. Should I pip install pycryptodome or should i import the library before I use pdfplumber?

Comment: Sorry for this answer - I'm developing Python just with an online compiler, so I can't answer your question **how to install a library**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and my solution involved one of the two pathways:

1- The PDF was encrypted and I did not know it. Here's an easy way to find out:

!pip install PyPDF2

import PyPDF2

if (PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file_name[-12:], 'rb')).isEncrypted):

print('encrypted')

else:

print('not encrypted)

If it is encrypted, even with no passwords, you have to figure out how to solve the issue from the source who encrypted it.

2- Solved it by executing the following two steps:

```
$ pip install crypto
```

---

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
```

Alternatively, you could probably just install the `arc4` module:

```
$ pip install arc4
```

---

```
from arc4 import ARC4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a lower version worked for me

```
$ pip install pycryptodome==3.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem:
AttributeError: function/symbol 'SHA256_init' not found in library ... _SHA256.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so